# Yii2 set array form field as required in model

Tags: php, validation, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

If I have the following form field (code below) how can I set the field as required within my model so that like other fields the form cannot be submitted without it containing information.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'seo[seo_title]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 60])->label('SEO Title') ?>
```

Comment: What is your `$model` variable? Add your model code.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `value` for te textinput in the options eg:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'seo[seo_title]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 60], 'value'=> $yourValue )->label('SEO Title') ?>
```

or if you only need these fields required mark required in the model